# Getting "Trust anchor for certification path not found." for a service that used to work

Tags: android, https, retrofit, okhttp

I am getting the infamous `SSLHandshake` exception since yesterday for a
[service](https://localizador.correos.es/canonico/eventos_envio_servicio/CODE?codAplicacion=60&codCanal=3&codIdioma=ES&indUltEvento=N) that has worked forever. As I understand this would happen when the HTTPs certificate has been signed by a CA not included in the OS.

However I've tried this URL straight into Chrome both on desktop and mobile (vanilla Android) and they both claim the certificate to be valid and from a known CA.

How come this started suddenly from yesterday, without any change whatsoever on my code? This serive is from a third party (parcel tracking) so I can't include their certificate within my app.

Am I missing something here? I'm using Retrofit + Moshi + OkHttp

This is the entire stacktrace Im getting:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:229)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:367)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:325)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:197)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:249)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:108)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:76)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:245)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:96)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.684 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:100)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:197)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:148)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:204)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:46)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:35)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12267)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleMap.subscribeActual(SingleMap.java:34)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap$SingleFlatMapCallback.onSuccess(SingleFlatMap.java:84)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.685 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSuccess$DoOnSuccess.onSuccess(SingleDoOnSuccess.java:60)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.686 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate$Emitter.onSuccess(SingleCreate.java:67)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.686 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at androidx.room.RxRoom$5.subscribe(RxRoom.java:229)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.686 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleCreate.subscribeActual(SingleCreate.java:39)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.686 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.686 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSuccess.subscribeActual(SingleDoOnSuccess.java:35)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.686 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.686 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap.subscribeActual(SingleFlatMap.java:36)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.686 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.686 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleFlatMap.subscribeActual(SingleFlatMap.java:36)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.686 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.686 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSuccess.subscribeActual(SingleDoOnSuccess.java:35)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3603)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:578)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:646)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:495)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:418)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:339)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:208)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:404)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.687 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:375)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.688 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:224)
2020-07-09 18:04:04.688 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:  ... 49 more
2020-07-09 18:04:04.688 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
2020-07-09 18:04:04.688 10577-10577/net.kelmer.correostracker.debug E/ParcelListViewModel$refresh:  ... 60 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the server is serving an incomplete chain, Firefox is able to work around this.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=localizador.correos.es&latest

Chain issues    Incomplete

```
 Path #1: Trusted
1   Sent by server  localizador.correos.es
Fingerprint SHA256: 9665607354d2caa7990b2b5771a7aea0b598902df8814f6ca07f5dd6e3f69f89
Pin SHA256: uAsu6QaEo1pYjkzUnsW/IK9oJDdbEF8TQ5xfVGSXCX0=
RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA256withRSA

2   Extra download  Entrust Certification Authority - L1K
Fingerprint SHA256: 13efb39a2f6654e8c67bd04f4c6d4c90cd6cab5091bcedc73787f6b77d3d3fe7
Pin SHA256: 980Ionqp3wkYtN9SZVgMzuWQzJta1nfxNPwTem1X0uc=
RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA256withRSA

3   In trust store  Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2   Self-signed 
Fingerprint SHA256: 43df5774b03e7fef5fe40d931a7bedf1bb2e6b42738c4e6d3841103d3aa7f339
Pin SHA256: du6FkDdMcVQ3u8prumAo6t3i3G27uMP2EOhR8R0at/U=
RSA 2048 bits (e 65537) / SHA256withRSA
```

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by putting their intermediate certificate in a custom trustmanager, so you might be right!